# Drawing video frames (images) - ios

Tags: ios, opengl-es, video-processing

I'm working on a project and one of the features is to play a video from a rtmp path. I'm trying to find the best way to draw the frames. Right now I'm using a UIImageView and works, but It's not very elegant nor efficient. OpenGL might do the trick but I've never used it before. Do you have some ideas what should I use? If you agree with OpenGL can you give me a code snippet that I could use for drawing the frames?

Thank you.

Comment: You could look at what I do here: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage in the GPUImageMovie class, although that pull from local movies via AV Foundation.

Comment: @bradLarson, I have same problem like you " that's some drawing on videos and save on iPhone , so please give me some suggestion.